# How to open Telerik Report File .trdx file in WPF using C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, reporting-services, telerik

I am using Stand alone Report Designer tool of Telerik. This creates a .trdx file. Now, on button click i want to show this report using ReportViewer. is it possible in WPF application?

[View Report Designer](http://www.telerik.com/products/reporting/report-designer.aspx)

Help Appreciated!

Comment: just start a process (the reoprt designer executable) and pass the file as first argument?

Comment: i have tried this but it opens in designer mode not in preview mode..! any other solution?

Answer (score 2):

Report Designer != ReportViewer. You should use one of Telerik's ReportSources to set your .trdx file as source and assign that ReportSource to the WPF ReportViewer. Check the following links:

- http://www.telerik.com/help/reporting/report-sources.html
- http://www.telerik.com/help/reporting/standalone-report-designer-display-report-viewer.html